# whats is the best way of dealing with php audio and webcam?

Tags: php, html, audio, webcam

is thier a guideline of how i can deal with playing around with audios and recording webcams, and what file formats i should use for optimisation, and plus any poplaur modules, plugins and classes that i can use to prevent re-inventing the wheel. im really looking at using this kind of stuff for user generated content. basically im looking for good advice, on how i should deal with kind of stuff? thanks :)) sorry for the broad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [red5](http://osflash.org/red5). It's a flash streaming server which can record and play back webcam streams. There are also commercial alternatives such as Wowza Media Server and Adobe Flash Media Server. All of these are flash based though. I don't know of any HTML5 based approaches.